# How can my function check if every field is populated on dynamically created fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't use

```
 $(document).on('', function
```

due to this being a function that is called after another function. I need a previous function to trigger this on an if statement and for it then to check all dynamic fields.

My code is the following:

```
function checkfunctions() {

 var value = $('.requiredClass:visible').filter(function () {
    return this.value === '';
  });
  debugger;
  if (value.length == 0) {
        rcheck()
  } else if (value.length > 0) { 
    alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
  }
};
```

and I have html like the following:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="requiredClass"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="requiredClass"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="requiredClass"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="requiredClass"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="verificationType">Check Function</button>
```

Along with dynamically created rows.

The code works for the first row and for all the other fields with the same class on the form but then when I create another row it does not check it for values.

This function chain triggers on a button at the bottom of the page.
tia

EDIT:

This is where the function is called:

```
            function ShowAlert1() {
        var email = document.getElementById('Text3');
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
                $("#emailInvalid").show();
                alert("Please Make sure your email address is valid")
                email.focus;
                return false;
    }
    else {
                checkfunctions(); //Checks if emails are valid, then checks if fields are populated
    }
 }
```

Edit2:  ShowAlert1() comes from:

```
         $('.verificationType').on('click', function () {
             var password = $("#p1").val();
             var confirmPassword = $("#Text3").val();
             if (password != confirmPassword) {
                 alert("Please Make sure emails match");
             } else {
             ShowAlert1(); 
             }

});
```

So when verificationType is clicked, this is triggered.

Comment: when you are calling `checkfunctions()`?

Comment: added it in there, it checks if the email is valid, then checks the fields are populated. I may have a solution that I'm working on. Will update answer if I do

Comment: and when is `ShowAlert1()` called?

Comment: Sorry, I put it in

Comment: I am sorry but its totally confusing now.. Could you provide a minimal working example in `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Ill see if I can get it in a fiddle. Basically I'm clicking a button. That is checking if an email address matches a previous field for confirmation. Then it checks if it's a valid email address and then it checks all the fields with the class "requiredClass" to see if they are populated. This last bit only works on the static fields and not ones created in my dynamic table.

Comment: Yea, got your point. But it would be helpful if we see these types of questions in practical.. :) Take your time.. I am here..